# Каптча Kohana 3.2

Tags: jquery, php, kohana

[По этой](http://wadya.pp.ua/2011/12/13/captcha-kohana/) инструкции все сделал, вывел каптчу `echo $captcha->render();` только не понятно, как сделать, чтобы при клике обновлялась, а именно

> Для организации смены картинки на странице на более читаемую воспользуемся вспомогательным элементом, к которому присоеденим функцию на `onclick` и с помощью `jquery` изменим картинку:`function reload() {
>     id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
>     $("img.captcha").attr("src", "/captcha/default?id=" + id);
> }`

Как сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все сделал сам:

```
<a onclick="reload()" style="cursor: pointer;"><?php  $captcha = Captcha::instance();
echo $captcha->render(); ?></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function reload(){
id=Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000);
$("img.captcha").attr("src","/captcha/default?id="+id);
}
</script>
```